# Cross-platform alternative to a windows shell extension - WebDAV platform?

Tags: c#, java, iis, webdav

I want to build a cross-platform (windows, mac[, linux]) desktop application that allows directory browsing and drag-and-drop functionality for accessing a cloud-based enterprise CMS.  This will replace an existing (and slightly buggy) windows shell extension that talks to a REST API hosted by IIS.

I'm currently looking into leveraging WebDAV, but I'm having trouble finding a cross-platform library for building the client(s).  I'm looking for advice and suggestions for what technologies and/or libraries to leverage to make this project go smoothly.  My preferred languages are C# and Java, and an ideal solution would be able to map a drive. Also - I do have a budget and I don't mind supporting fellow programmers.

Thanks a ton for any ideas or knowledge you can provide.

Comment: Writing a WebDAV client is much easier than writing a WebDAV server. I would consider just rolling your own code to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You might have more joy implementing ssh and sftp. There are a number of very good graphical sftp clients such as [winscp](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

Most OS'es provide built-in WebDAV client that is installed by default in many cases. Windows provide Mini-redirector, Mac OS X provide Darvin, many Linuxs provide davfs2. You can mount a drive or map folder from OS UI or programmatically. Each OS and WebDAV client has its own specifics and sometimes [bugs](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/webdav-redirector-list.html#version-5.1.2600.5512).

With the release of IE 10 you can build an Ajax WebDAV client that runs in all 4 major browsers. Or deploy some existing client, like this one: [ajaxbrowser.com](http://ajaxbrowser.com).

Both cases may reduce your time building a cross-platform WebDAV client.